# Find the max date in a single column across multiple rows

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
id       <- c(1,1,2,3,3)
date     <- c("23-01-08","01-11-07","30-11-07","17-12-07","12-12-08")
df       <- data.frame(id,date)
df$date2 <- as.Date(as.character(df$date), format = "%d-%m-%y")


id     date      date2
1   23-01-08 2008-01-23
1   01-11-07 2007-11-01
2   30-11-07 2007-11-30
3   17-12-07 2007-12-17
3   12-12-08 2008-12-12
```

now I need to create a forth column and insert maximum date of transaction for each `id` in that.
the final table should be as follow:

```
id     date      date2        max
1   23-01-08 2008-01-23 2008-01-23
1   01-11-07 2007-11-01   0
2   30-11-07 2007-11-30 2007-11-30 
3   17-12-07 2007-12-17   0
3   12-12-08 2008-12-12 2008-12-12
```

I would be thankful if you could help me with this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
id<-c(1,1,2,3,3)
date<-c("23-01-08","01-11-07","30-11-07","17-12-07","12-12-08")
df<-data.frame(id,date)
df$date2<-as.Date(as.character(df$date), format = "%d-%m-%y")
# aggregate can be used for this type of thing
d = aggregate(df$date2,by=list(df$id),max)
# And merge the result of aggregate 
# with the original data frame
df2 = merge(df,d,by.x=1,by.y=1)
df2

  id     date      date2          x
1  1 23-01-08 2008-01-23 2008-01-23
2  1 01-11-07 2007-11-01 2008-01-23
3  2 30-11-07 2007-11-30 2007-11-30
4  3 17-12-07 2007-12-17 2008-12-12
5  3 12-12-08 2008-12-12 2008-12-12
```

Edit:  Since you want the last column to be "empty" when the date does not match the max date, you can try the next line.

```
df2[df2[,3]!=df2[,4],4]=NA

df2
  id     date      date2          x
1  1 23-01-08 2008-01-23 2008-01-23
2  1 01-11-07 2007-11-01       <NA>
3  2 30-11-07 2007-11-30 2007-11-30
4  3 17-12-07 2007-12-17       <NA>
5  3 12-12-08 2008-12-12 2008-12-12
```

Of course, it is always nice to clean up the colnames, etc., but I leave that for you.

Answer (score 11):

Another approach is to use the `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, "id", summarize, max = max(date2))

#  id        max
#1  1 2008-01-23
#2  2 2007-11-30
#3  3 2008-12-12
```

Now this isn't in the format you were after, as it only shows each `id` once. Never fear, we can use `transform` instead of `summarize`:

```
ddply(df, "id", transform, max = max(date2))

#  id     date      date2        max
#1  1 01-11-07 2007-11-01 2008-01-23
#2  1 23-01-08 2008-01-23 2008-01-23
#3  2 30-11-07 2007-11-30 2007-11-30
#4  3 12-12-08 2008-12-12 2008-12-12
#5  3 17-12-07 2007-12-17 2008-12-12
```

As in @seandavi's answer, this repeats the `max` date for each `id`. If you want to change the duplicates to `NA`, something like this will do the job:

```
within(ddply(df, "id", transform, max = max(date2)), max[max != date2] <- NA)
```

Answer (score 8):

Adding `dplyr` solution in case someone is looking:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(max = if_else(date2 == max(date2), date2, as.Date(NA)))
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   id [3]
     id     date      date2        max
  <dbl>   <fctr>     <date>     <date>
1     1 23-01-08 2008-01-23 2008-01-23
2     1 01-11-07 2007-11-01         NA
3     2 30-11-07 2007-11-30 2007-11-30
4     3 17-12-07 2007-12-17         NA
5     3 12-12-08 2008-12-12 2008-12-12
```

Comment: I use it this way: mutate(flag_last = if_else(date == max(date), TRUE, FALSE)) %>% filter(flag_last == TRUE)

Answer (score 2):

```
library(sqldf)
tables<- '(SELECT * FROM df
           )
           AS t1,
           (SELECT id,max(date2) date2 FROM df GROUP BY id
           )
           AS t2'

out<-fn$sqldf("SELECT t1.*,t2.date2 mdate FROM $tables WHERE  t1.id=t2.id")
out$mdate<-as.Date(out$mdate)
out$mdate[out$date2!=out$mdate]<-NA
#  id     date      date2      mdate
#1  1 01-11-07 2007-11-01       <NA>
#2  1 23-01-08 2008-01-23 2008-01-23
#3  2 30-11-07 2007-11-30 2007-11-30
#4  3 12-12-08 2008-12-12 2008-12-12
#5  3 17-12-07 2007-12-17       <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use 0 as a Date value, so you will either need to abandon keeping it as a Date or accept a NA value:

```
# Date values:
df$maxdt <- ave(df$date2, df$id, 
                    FUN=function(x) ifelse( x == max(x), as.character(x), NA) ) 
str(ave(df$date2, df$id, FUN=function(x) ifelse( x == max(x), as.character(x), NA) ) )
# Date[1:5], format: "2008-01-23" NA "2007-11-30" NA "2008-12-12"
```

The `ifelse` machinery does some strange type checking that defeats using just `x` as the second argument above, but still returns Date-class vector. Go figure! Below is the character vector option.

```
# Character values:
df$maxdt <- ave(as.character(df$date2), df$id, 
                   FUN=function(x) ifelse( x == max(x), x,  "0") )
ave(as.character(df$date2), df$id, FUN=function(x) ifelse( x == max(x), x,  "0") )
[1] "2008-01-23" "0"          "2007-11-30" "0"          "2008-12-12"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this to help when I want to see the min/max date of a column

Max: `head(df %>% distinct(date) %>% arrange(desc(date)))`
Min: `head(df %>% distinct(date) %>% arrange(date))`

The max will sort the date column in descending order, allowing you to see the max. The min will sort in ascending order, allowing you to see the min.

You need to use the `dplyr` package for this.