# Find first instance per group and fill to new column in R

Tags: r, date

I have the following df:

```
ID Date 
1  01/01/2018
2  01/01/2010
2  01/01/2012
2  01/01/2013
3  01/01/2015
3  01/01/2018
```

I have ordered the columns by ascending order by ID, but now would like to find the first instance of a date per ID (this would be the oldest date) and to fill a new column with this date.

So:

```
ID Date        NewDate
 1  01/01/2018 01/01/2018
 2  01/01/2010 01/01/2010
 2  01/01/2012 01/01/2010
 2  01/01/2013 01/01/2010
 3  01/01/2015 01/01/2015
 3  01/01/2018 01/01/2015
```

Any help appreciated as always.

Comment: Similar solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127149/find-the-max-date-in-a-single-column-across-multiple-rows). Possible duplicate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the max date in a single column across multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127149/find-the-max-date-in-a-single-column-across-multiple-rows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the data is already ordered , you could just get `first` value from each group

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(NewDate = first(Date))

#    ID Date       NewDate   
#  <int> <fct>      <fct>     
#1     1 01/01/2018 01/01/2018
#2     2 01/01/2010 01/01/2010
#3     2 01/01/2012 01/01/2010
#4     2 01/01/2013 01/01/2010
#5     3 01/01/2015 01/01/2015
#6     3 01/01/2018 01/01/2015
```

---

In Base R, we could use `ave`

```
df$NewDate <- with(df, ave(Date, ID, FUN = function(x) x[1]))

df
#  ID       Date    NewDate
#1  1 01/01/2018 01/01/2018
#2  2 01/01/2010 01/01/2010
#3  2 01/01/2012 01/01/2010
#4  2 01/01/2013 01/01/2010
#5  3 01/01/2015 01/01/2015
#6  3 01/01/2018 01/01/2015
```

---

We could also use `head` with `ave`

```
df$NewDate <- with(df, ave(Date, ID, FUN = head, 1))
```

---

Or as suggested by @Hugh, use `min` provided `Date` column is of "Date" class

```
df$NewDate <- with(df, ave(Date, ID, FUN = min))
```

In `dplyr` which would be

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(NewDate = min(Date))
```

Comment: Probably should add that a 'safe' option would be `min(Date)` (provided the class of `Date` is Date); unlikely to be much of a performance deficit.

Comment: @RonakShah - the base R solution with 'ave' worked fro me - thank you!