# r: How to format many columns at once based on specific column names from "as.character" to "as.Date" and subsequently find the most recent date?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, dplyr

How to extract the highest / most recent date across multiple rows?
[This similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127149/find-the-max-date-in-a-single-column-across-multiple-rows/12127177) did not provide a solution

I have multiple MRI scans on the same patient. I want to know what date is the most recent. Each patient may have up to 20 follow-ups, but does not necessarily have a MRI scan on each follow-up.

One problem is, that all MRI date columns are formatted `as.character`. Is possible to format all columns that contains `mr_daterd` in the column name to `as.Date("all columns containing mr_daterd in the name_id",  format = '%d.%m.%Y')`?

It seems too contraproductive to write `mutate(MRI_first = as.Date(mr_daterd_first,  format = '%d.%m.%Y')` on each and every date column.

Subsequently, I would like to find the most recent date, here defined as `p$max_date`:

```
> head(p)
   mr_daterd mr_daterd_fu1 mr_daterd_fu1_v2 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4     ...
1 07.03.2011    20.03.2012       05.06.2013          10.09.2014             18.01.2017     ...
2 15.04.1999          <NA>             <NA>          22.02.2000                   <NA>     ...
3 xx/xx/2007    25.05.2012             <NA>                <NA>                   <NA>     ...
4 18.09.2006          <NA>             <NA>                <NA>                   <NA>     ...
```

Expected output

```
> head(p)
   mr_daterd mr_daterd_fu1 mr_daterd_fu1_v2 mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3    ...   max_date
1 07.03.2011    20.03.2012       05.06.2013          10.09.2014    ...   13.04.2018
2 15.04.1999          <NA>             <NA>          22.02.2000    ...   30.05.2007
3 xx/xx/2007    25.05.2012             <NA>                <NA>    ...   25.05.2012
4 18.09.2006          <NA>             <NA>                <NA>    ...   18.09.2006
```

A solution in `dplyr` in preferred.

Data

```
p <- structure(list(mr_daterd = c("07.03.2011", "15.04.1999", "xx/xx/2007", 
"18.09.2006"), mr_daterd_fu1 = c("20.03.2012", NA, "25.05.2012", 
NA), mr_daterd_fu1_v2 = c("05.06.2013", NA, NA, NA), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3 = c("10.09.2014", 
"22.02.2000", NA, NA), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4 = c("18.01.2017", 
NA, NA, NA), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6 = c("18.01.2017", 
NA, NA, NA), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7 = c(NA, "09.04.2001", 
NA, NA), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8 = c("13.04.2018", 
NA, NA, NA), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10 = c(NA, 
"07.03.2002", NA, NA), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12 = c(NA, 
"05.02.2003", NA, NA), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15 = c(NA, 
"29.03.2004", NA, NA), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17 = c(NA, 
"13.04.2005", NA, NA), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18_v19 = c(NA, 
"30.05.2007", NA, NA), mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18_v19_v20 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA), n_mri = c(7, 8, 2, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You can use `across()` and `starts_with()` to transform to dates and then applying at row level the function `c_across()` can help to obtain the maximum date. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
p %>% mutate(across(starts_with('mr_daterd'),~as.Date(.,'%d.%m.%Y'))) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Recent=max(c_across(starts_with('mr_daterd')),na.rm = T)) -> p1
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 23
# Rowwise: 
  mr_daterd  mr_daterd_fu1 mr_daterd_fu1_v2 mr_daterd_fu1_v~ mr_daterd_fu1_v~
  <date>     <date>        <date>           <date>           <date>          
1 2011-03-07 2012-03-20    2013-06-05       2014-09-10       2017-01-18      
2 1999-04-15 NA            NA               2000-02-22       NA              
3 NA         2012-05-25    NA               NA               NA              
4 2006-09-18 NA            NA               NA               NA              
# ... with 18 more variables: mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5 <date>,
#   mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6 <date>, mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7 <date>,
#   mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8 <date>,
#   mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9 <date>,
#   mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10 <date>,
#   mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11 <date>,
#   mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12 <date>,
#   mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13 <date>,
#   mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14 <date>,
#   mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15 <date>,
#   mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16 <date>,
#   mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17 <date>,
#   mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18 <date>,
#   mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18_v19 <date>,
#   mr_daterd_fu1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18_v19_v20 <date>,
#   n_mri <dbl>, Recent <date>
```

**Update:** If the rowwise is not desired, try reshaping to long to obtain the max and then merge by a common id defined by row:

```
#Code 2
new <- p %>%
  mutate(id=row_number(),
         across(starts_with('mr_daterd'),~as.Date(.,'%d.%m.%Y'))) %>%
  left_join(
    p %>%
      mutate(id=row_number(),
             across(starts_with('mr_daterd'),~as.Date(.,'%d.%m.%Y'))) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('mr_daterd')) %>%
      group_by(id) %>%
      summarise(Recent=max(value,na.rm=T))
  ) %>% select(-id)
```

Comment: Hi @Duck. Thank you as always. This format to `as.Date()` was great. Is it possible to find the most recent date without going through `rowwise()`? The dataset is very large, hence the datamanagement is comprehensive, and `rowwise()` kinda messes that up.

Comment: @cmirian Hi dear! It is possible without rowwise but we would have to use `apply()` which is similar or if you want I could add a code to reshape data to long and then extract the date, please tell me which one you would like!

Comment: Thank you. Well, I cant tell exactly because it is above my current skill level. I have a huge dataset with 907 rows x 1855 columns. I am not sure which one would best. Is it possible to reshape to long and then back?

Comment: @cmirian I have added an update with reshaping, please let me know if that works !

Comment: Thank you @Duck :)

Comment: @cmirian Always a pleasure :)